Desktop doesn't come up
I have no idea what happened. After rebooting Ubuntu 24.04 it gets stuck at this screen. Only pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del works to reboot. I type my disk encryption password, it decrypts, and then this comes up.
How can I recover?

Update:
On the screen given below I pressed Alt+F2 to open the console then logged into my account.
Then I tried startx command. It failed, but I got xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
Google'd it and found same problem here
I reinstalled gnome-desktop:
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
Then typed startx to get into desktop.

Have you tried pressing  at boot to invoke the grub menu? Once you are in the grub menu, you should try booting using a different boot option.

Different booting options didn't work for me. But I managed to work it out.

Sounds like you came up with an answer? If so, then instead of adding it to your question, you can create your own answer and the click the checkmark to indicated that it solved your issue.
